# onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult

I tried many approaches after reading muliple web pages, however, I can't make a roundtrip of an object between two activities and a fragment.

Overview: The object is a `Serializable` object describing a Meal (something you eat). I have a `MainActivity` using a Fragment with a `ListView` listing Meal objects. When I click on a meal in the `ListView` a `MealEditorActivity` is started using the *startActivityForResult* method. This works all fine. I can edit the Meal object in this activity.

Problem: When I click back in the `MealEditorActivity` menu bar, I want to send the edited Meal object back, but neither *onActivityResult* in the Fragment nor in the `MainActivity` is called.

What am I doing wrong?

Code Snippets:

```
... 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // add a button below the listview to create new Meal entries
        Button newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_meal_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               ...
            }
        });
    } 
   ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult in MainActivity triggered");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

and this is how the `MealEditorActivity` is started from the Fragment when a Meal is clicked ..

```
...
public class MainFragmentMealList extends Fragment {

private static final String LOG_TAG = MainFragmentMealList.class.getSimpleName();

protected List<Meal> mealList;

protected final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

public MainFragmentMealList() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mealList = new ArrayList<Meal>();

    // if no data exists in database, the generate some test data
    if(mealList.size() == 0) {
        Meal meal = new Meal();
        meal.setId(mealList.size()+1);
        meal.test();
        mealList.add(meal);
        meal = new Meal();
        meal.setId(mealList.size()+1);
        meal.test2();
        mealList.add(meal);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Meal> mealListeAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    getActivity(), // Die aktuelle Umgebung (diese Activity)
                    R.layout.meal_list_item, // ID der XML-Layout Datei
                    R.id.meal_list_item_textview, // ID des TextViews
                    mealList); // Beispieldaten in einer ArrayList

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meallist_main, container, false);

    ListView mealListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_mealliste);
    mealListView.setAdapter(mealListeAdapter);

    mealListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Meal selMeal = (Meal) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MealEditorActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(MealEditorActivity.EDIT_MEAL_TAG, selMeal);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult triggered: " + requestCode);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Meal meal = (Meal) data.getExtras().getSerializable(MealEditorActivity.REPLY_MEAL_TAG);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Date@onActivityResult : " + meal.getDate());            
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
...
```

the MealEditorActivity, that should send the result from the finish method..

```
...
public class MealEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MealEditorActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String EDIT_MEAL_TAG = "EDIT_MEAL";
    public static final String REPLY_MEAL_TAG = "REPLY_MEAL";

    protected Meal meal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor_meal);

        // get the meal object from the MainActivity to be edited
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        meal = (Meal) intent.getSerializableExtra(EDIT_MEAL_TAG);

        // initialize widgets in the view with data from meal object
        // and create listeners to update the meal object with user edits
        ...
     }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Date@finish : " + meal.getDate());
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra(MealEditorActivity.REPLY_MEAL_TAG, meal);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        super.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    // This one is triggered if the back button is clicked in the menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.levin.symptomdiary">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MealEditorActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_editor_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.levin.symptomdiary.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I use a newly installed `Android Studio` with an Mobile `Emulator`, `Android 4.4` Target.

This is my very first Android development, therefore, any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: can you also include the `manifest.xml` file?

Comment: You can save your meal items into your app local DB. And when you are moving to next activity by clicking the meal item just pass the meal item id (if any) or position to it. And on next activity retrieve all the meal items and try to find out your item by running the for loop. Once you are able to find the item and updated it just update the meal items (ALL) into the DB and when you press back button on current activity the onResume() of first activity will run, in that function you can retrieve the meal items and refresh your list items due to this you are able to see the changes in the list

Comment: Are you sure eitherOnBackPressed or onBackPressed is called?

Comment: I added the AndroidManifest.xml above

Comment: @howdoidothis: onBackPressed is never called. However, onOptionsItemSelected  is called when I click the back arrow in the menu.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma:  Thank you for the suggestion. I thought about this alternative and will implement it if noone can come up with a solution to the current design implementation - which should work according to all these web pages out there.